# Find occurences of any value in an array in a string and print it

Tags: python

I know this ones going to be something super simple, but it's just not working for me.

```
INDICATORS = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
STRING_1 = 'There was a tree with a bird in it'
STRING_2 = 'The dog was eating a bone'
STRING_3 = "Rick didn't let morty have a cat"


def FindIndicators(TEXT):
    if any(x in TEXT for x in INDICATORS):
        print x # 'x' being what I hoped was whatever the match would be (dog, cat)
```

Expected output:

```
FindIndicators(STRING_1)
# bird

FindIndicators(STRING_2)
# dog

FindIndicators(STRING_3)
# cat
```

Instead I'm getting an unsolved reference for 'x'. I have a feeling I'm going to face desk as soon as I see an answer.

Comment: `x` is scoped to only exist inside the list comprehension. You'll have to actually retrieve a value from the iterable to be able to use it. I recommend the built-in [next](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#next)

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how `any()` works. It consumes whatever you give it and returns True or False. `x` doesn't exist after.

```
>>> INDICATORS = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
>>> TEXT = 'There was a tree with a bird in it'
>>> [x in TEXT for x in INDICATORS]
[False, False, True]
>>> any(x in TEXT for x in INDICATORS)
True
```

Instead do this:

```
>>> for x in INDICATORS:
...     if x in TEXT:
...         print x
...
bird
```

Comment: Much appreciated, this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Keep in mind that `if x in TEXT` matches substrings, so `cat` will match `category` and `scattered`. You may want to use the test that @prune used: `if x in TEXT.split()` which says is `x` one of the entire words in TEXT.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation, **any** returns a Boolean value, not a list of matches.  All that call does is to indicate the presence of at least one "hit".

The variable **x** exists only within the generator expression; it's gone in the line after, so you can't print it.

```
INDICATORS = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
STRING_1 = 'There was a tree with a bird in it'
STRING_2 = 'The dog was eating a bone'
STRING_3 = "Rick didn't let morty have a cat"


def FindIndicators(TEXT):
    # This isn't the most Pythonic way,
    #   but it's near to your original intent
    hits = [x for x in TEXT.split() if x in INDICATORS]
    for x in hits:
        print x

print FindIndicators(STRING_1)
# bird

print FindIndicators(STRING_2)
# dog

print FindIndicators(STRING_3)
# cat
```